# Writing to %USERPROFILE% issue

Tags: vb.net

I have an IO program that I just finished except for one thing. I want the program to automatically detect the User's Profile without hard coding their profile into it. This is what I have now and that works.

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("C:\Users\Joshua\Documents\Horoscope\Monthly.txt", Chr(34) & finish & Chr(34), True)
```

And this is what I want, that doesn't work.

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("C:\Users\%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Horoscope\Monthly.txt", Chr(34) & finish & Chr(34), True)
```

Is there any way to get this to work? The error is telling me that the path doesn't exist. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I noticed you're writing to your Documents folder. This folder can be [redirected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folder_redirection), and so that specific folder name might not even exist for some profiles. You should let the system tell you not only where the user's profile is, but where the user's Documents folder is located, like this:

```
Dim fileName As String = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "Horoscope", "Monthly.txt")
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(fileName, Chr(34) & finish & Chr(34), True)
```

Comment: I just wrote this for my girlfriend. I'll definitely add this as a note though in the program for future reference. Thanks!

Comment: This is a more solid answer. I would use this.

Answer (score 1):

Use this to build your path:

```
Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("userprofile"), "Documents\Horoscope\Monthly.txt")
```

**Documentation:**

- [Path.Combine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77zkk0b6(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Use that instead of the entire line that I had? Or what would it replace?

Comment: It replaces this: `"C:\Users\%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Horoscope\Monthly.txt"`